# App on OSX 10.6.8 returns exit code 173 but doesn't prompt for iTunes credentials

Tags: objective-c, macos, app-store

I have an app that I list in the app store and I'm trying to test it on OSX 10.6.8. Unfortunately it appears my receipt validation code is preventing the app from running.

From: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW11

> After you launch your application, the following occurs:
>
> - Your application fails to validate its receipt because there is no
>     receipt present, and it exits with a status of 173.
> - The system
>     interprets the exit status and attempts to obtain a valid receipt.
>     Assuming your application signing certificate is valid, the system
>     installs a valid receipt for the application.
> - The system may prompt
>     you for your iTunes credentials. The system relaunches your
>     application, and your application successfully validates the receipt.

This works perfectly on OSX 10.8 and 10.7 but on 10.6, I'm never prompted for iTunes credentials when the app exits with code 173 (verified in Console.app).

Any idea what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Update: also see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW7